# How do I search a table that is created with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, search

I have a table that is created by javascript when it obtains data from the data base, this is the function

```
 function gotCData(snapshot){
            snapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => {
              var confirmed = userSnapshot.val().confirmed;
              var date = userSnapshot.val().date;
              var deaths = userSnapshot.val().deaths;
              var recovered = userSnapshot.val().recovered;
              //console.log(confirmed, date, deaths, recovered);
              var local = k;
        var csvDate = date;
        var population = recovered;
        var totalCases = confirmed;
        var totalDeaths = deaths;        

        //console.log(location);
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        var td2 = document.createElement('td');
        var td3 = document.createElement('td');
        var td4 = document.createElement('td');
        var td5 = document.createElement('td');

        var tdLocal = document.createTextNode(local);
        var tdPopulation = document.createTextNode(population);
        var tdTotalCases = document.createTextNode(totalCases);
        var tdTotalDeaths = document.createTextNode(totalDeaths);
        var tdDate = document.createTextNode(csvDate);
        td1.appendChild(tdLocal)
        td2.appendChild(tdPopulation)
        td3.appendChild(tdTotalCases)
        td4.appendChild(tdTotalDeaths)
        td5.appendChild(tdDate)
        var tRow1 = document.getElementById("displayCorona").appendChild(td1);
        var tRow2 = document.getElementById("displayCorona").appendChild(td2);
        var tRow3 = document.getElementById("displayCorona").appendChild(td3);
        var tRow4 = document.getElementById("displayCorona").appendChild(td4);
        var tRow5 = document.getElementById("displayCorona").appendChild(td5);
        //Writes the Table Row then the Divs after
        document.getElementById("displayCorona").appendChild(tr, tRow1, tRow2, tRow3, tRow4, tRow5);
            });
        }
```

I have a search function :

```
function search(){
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("displayCorona");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td1")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The tables are created when I loop through each node in a Firebase database. The search function is from W3Schools but im not sure why it is not searching the table that is created by the above function.

Comment: Your first function only creates 1 `tr` - yet you set row1, row2 etc. Have a look at the generated table using the developer tools - it wont be valid.

Comment: Is your input id really ```myInput```. Please look and report errors displayed in developer console if any!

Comment: @AnkurParihar yes the input id is myInput

Comment: @enhzflep the table generates correctly though. Screenshot : http://prntscr.com/sm8hdk

Comment: @Nick - certainly I can see that the table appears to display correctly. It does however appear from the code to be invalid. That's why the suggestion of the DevTools - they give you a clearer view of what's actually happening. If your code supplied data, created a table for it and then searched for a known-present entry, I'd try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code for you to look at.

```js
"use strict";
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false);
function onLoad(evt)
{
 var inputStr = "I have a table that is created by javascript when it obtains data from the data base, this is the function";
 document.body.appendChild( makeTable(inputStr) );
 byId('goBtn').addEventListener('click', onGoBtn, false);
}

function makeTable(input)
{
 let tbl = newEl('table');
 
 input = input.replace(',', '');
 let words = input.split(' ');
 let nWords = words.length;
 let nRows = parseInt(nWords/5) + nWords%5;
 
 for (var j=0; j<nRows; j++)
 {
  let tr = newEl('tr');
  for (var col=0; col<5; col++)
  {
   let td = newEl('td');
   td.textContent = words[j*5 + col];
   tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tr);
 }
 return tbl;
}

function highlightContainingCells(input, highlightClassname)
{
 let cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
 cells.forEach( cellFunc );
 function cellFunc(curCell)
 {
  if (input == curCell.textContent)
   curCell.classList.add(highlightClassname);
  else
   curCell.classList.remove(highlightClassname);
 }
}

function onGoBtn(evt)
{
 let str = byId('searchStr').value;
 highlightContainingCells(str, "found");
}
```

```css
td
{
 color: #333;
 background-color: #ddd;
}
td.found
{
 color: #ddd;
 background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<input id='searchStr' value='javascript'/><button id='goBtn'>SEARCH</button></br>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were so many wrong things.

- You had not specified what data type `snapshot` is. Is it array or something else? I assumed it to be array of JSON objects, where each object denotes a row in your table.
- I did not understand the use of `.val()` method. I removed it completely.
- The table being generates was not in correct format. You were appending `tr` to table. But instead of appending `td` to `tr` you were also appending them to table. I have corrected that also.
- There was an undefined variable `k` which was being used to set local.
- `display:block` style on `tr` was displaying table in a weird way once rows are eliminated. I changed it to `display:table-row` instead, which is ideal for table-rows

```js
function gotCData(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => {
        var confirmed = userSnapshot.val().confirmed;
        var date = userSnapshot.val().date;
        var deaths = userSnapshot.val().deaths;
        var recovered = userSnapshot.val().recovered;
        var local = userSnapshot.local;    // we will look at this later
        // console.log(confirmed, date, deaths, recovered);
        // var local = k;
        var csvDate = date;
        var population = recovered;
        var totalCases = confirmed;
        var totalDeaths = deaths;

        //console.log(location);
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        var td2 = document.createElement('td');
        var td3 = document.createElement('td');
        var td4 = document.createElement('td');
        var td5 = document.createElement('td');

        var tdLocal = document.createTextNode(local);
        var tdPopulation = document.createTextNode(population);
        var tdTotalCases = document.createTextNode(totalCases);
        var tdTotalDeaths = document.createTextNode(totalDeaths);
        var tdDate = document.createTextNode(csvDate);
        td1.appendChild(tdLocal)
        td2.appendChild(tdPopulation)
        td3.appendChild(tdTotalCases)
        td4.appendChild(tdTotalDeaths)
        td5.appendChild(tdDate)

        tr.appendChild(td1)
        tr.appendChild(td2)
        tr.appendChild(td3)
        tr.appendChild(td4)
        tr.appendChild(td5)

        // Writes the Table Row then the Divs after
        document.getElementById("displayCorona").appendChild(tr);
    });
}

function search() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("displayCorona");
    tr = table.querySelectorAll("tr:not(.table-head)");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    var found
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")
        if (tds) {
            found = false
            for (j = 0; j < tds.length && found == false; j++) {
                td = tds[j];
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "table-row";
                    found = true
                    break
                }
            }
            if (found == false) tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

// This is used for testing only
// window.onload = () => {
//     snapshot = firebaseToArray(firebaseJSON)
//     gotCData(snapshot)
// }
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
  
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
  
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <input type="text" id="myInput">
 <button type="submit" onclick="search()">Search</button>
 <table id="displayCorona">
  <tr class="table-head">
   <th>Location</th>
   <th>Population</th>
   <th>Total cases</th>
   <th>Total deaths</th>
   <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>

</html>
```

*Some friendly advice:*

- I see you have extracted data from snapshot and assign them twice to variables, for say you first extract `date` from snapshot and then assign it to `csvDate`, while you could directly extract date to `csvDate`
- You were creating text nodes for td, assigning them values and appending them to corresponding td node. You could directly insert data using `innerHTML` or `innerText` for example, `td1.innerText = local`. No need to create textNodes and append them!
- It seems like you directly copy-pasted code for `search` function from w3schools. Please review such codes after using.
- Use [developer console](https://javascript.info/devtools) to find common errors. [Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript) your code can solves many common problems, so get familiar with it.

Comment: Hey, i tested with the snapshot that you created .... That search function works, but when I try it with my code , it still shows the full list of countries, even though i type in the search bar which country i want to search

Comment: Did you replace your code with my code? Give me a sample of your snapshot data! Most likely the issue is with the format Firebase is returning data. Upload a sample of snapshot on https://pastebin.com/ and share with me

Comment: http://prntscr.com/sme4ox this is what the database looks like and this is what it looks like in the dev console : http://prntscr.com/sme623

Comment: The snapshot is the data that im parsing in right? 
if so , the data taht i am obtaining is from here https://github.com/pomber/covid19/blob/master/docs/timeseries.json

Comment: Yes this is the problem, this data is incompatible with what we're using. I will convert this

Comment: Ill give it a go :)

Comment: I tried implementing your code , but now the tables doesnt display at all :(
I have included a pastebin of the code https://pastebin.com/NLL5wYFM 
I really do appreciate your help with this. I am extremely grateful.

Comment: Please try the updated ```gotCData``` function again. All the wrong things are happening due to how firebase is sending data. Although this is getting out of scope of question, let us solve this :)